# String tokenizer via UDF

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am trying to implement strings tokenizer in Excel via UDF using C# and Excel-Dna. Personally I found the mIRC's function [`$gettok`](http://www.mirchelp.net/helpfile/token_identifiers.htm) pretty useful due to the lack of string functions in Excel.

**Examples**

```
getTok("Aquel que no espera vencer ya esta vencido",   1, 32) -> "Aquel"
getTok("Aquel que no espera vencer ya esta vencido",  -1, 32) -> "vencido"
getTok("Aquel que no espera vencer ya esta vencido", 2-4, 32) -> "que no espera"
getTok("Aquel que no espera vencer ya esta vencido",   0, 32) -> "Aquel que no espera vencer ya esta vencido"
```

**Code**

```
[ExcelFunction(Category="String Utilities", Name = "getTok")]
public static string getTok(string text, string token, int delimiter)
{
    int from = 0;
    int to = 0;

    string tokenPatter = @"(\d+)(-)(\d+)?";
    string[] tokens = text.Split(new char[] { (char)delimiter });

    Regex tokenRegex = new Regex(tokenPatter, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match tokenMatch = tokenRegex.Match(token);

    if (tokenMatch.Success)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        from = short.Parse(tokenMatch.Groups[0].Value);

        if (tokenMatch.Groups.Count == 1) to = from;
        else if (tokenMatch.Groups.Count == 2) to = (short)tokens.Length;
        else to = short.Parse(tokenMatch.Groups[2].Value);

        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(tokens[i - 1] + ((char)delimiter));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    int index = int.Parse(token);
    if (index > 0) return tokens[index - 1];
    else return tokens[tokens.Length + index];    
}
```

**Questions**

- What would you improve on?
- Have you tried something similar with Excel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this statement:

```
for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(tokens[i - 1] + ((char)delimiter));
    }
```

The way that you have it written, I don't think that `i` will ever hit `to`.

Also, I would change some variable names to make it more readable. `from` and `to` got confusing, I had to keep telling myself that those are variables.  I recommend doing something like:

```
int intFrom;
int intTo;
```

at the very least, so that you automatically know that those are integer variables.

Also you have an `int` for a delimiter? Why not just pass a `char` as a delimiter?

Other than that I think the code looks good.

Comment: +1 for renaming the variables; I think `from` cause issues if you're `using System.Linq`?

Comment: @retailcoder I believe a variable called `from` won't cause any issues, unless you try to use it in an LINQ expression.

Comment: I don't think prefixing `from` and `to` with the types make very good variable names. If you're going to be more verbose, you might as well use names like `fromIndex` and `toIndex`.

Comment: it was more of an `at least prefix the variables` type of thing,  not `this is the best practice` type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `getTok` should be `GetToken` or `Tokens`. Don't overly abbreviate things, this goes doubly for any public API. However, even the verbose forms of those aren't good names. This function doesn't really tokenize things, or return tokens.

From the point of view of an Excel user, it seems to just be an odd way of getting a substring and it's not obvious how I'm supposed to call your function or what it should return to me.

I recommend putting more thought into your public API and utilizing the `[ExcelArgument]` attribute to better document it.

As a quick aside, I found this nifty looking tool that generates actual documents from ExcelDna attributes. 
You may find it of interest.

http://mndrake.github.io/ExcelDnaDoc/index.html